# Android sliding menu using navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I am trying to work on a project which has sliding menu.But i want to run it on api level 8.So i used the support library for the result.But the app is force closing.The code for the main class is :

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

//          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                  .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

The LOGCAT:

```
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.androidhive.slidingmenu-1.apk]
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.androidhive.slidingmenu-1.apk]
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
08-20 14:29:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    ... 11 more
```

Please help!!

Comment: post your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you declared in manifest and menu file. However please check whether you declared this.

in manifest file:

```
<application
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

 in menu file:
```

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto

Check whether you mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a class not found exception , this could be due to not building the app, try building the project and if still exist clean and build again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't added **MainActivity** in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

Add below code inside **<application>** tag

```
<activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```